# I have just accidentally uninstalled synaptic manager. How do I install it again?

Tags: 13.10, software-center, synaptic

I uninstalled it from the software center....once it happened, I wanted to install it again, but it shows that it is there (weird).
I did an update and it is gone from the PPA.

How can I install it again or check if it is there or damaged? 
Is it really important to have the synaptic manager if I mainly use the software manager?

Comment: Use apt-get as suggested below, but do not panic, you can do everything that synaptic does with apt-get itself. There are also other alternatives for installing such as aptitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these commands in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get purge synaptic    
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall synaptic
```

Yes,it was really important.You can easily check which packages are installed and which are not installed through synaptic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just done the 1st option, but when I update from the terminal, I get these messages:
"W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

How can I update and put the synaptic PPA again?

Comment: pls post the error report in pastebin.com and provide me the link.

Comment: Thanks again. This is the part with the error message:
http://pastebin.com/fBJ38gVh

Comment: you don't need to update from the terminal,just run the above commands.

Comment: I have already run that command and synaptic is already installed. but I am wondering why the ppa is giving me this error message when I update my system from the terminal?

Comment: there was no synapse core for ubuntu 13.10,see this https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ppa .If you don't want this error message to come again,you have delete the lines `ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/` from `/etc/apt/sources.list`